# Cleos Create Account Problem

Tags: cleos, accounts

I try to create account by cleos cli.
But it always return this :
Error 3120006: No available wallet
Ensure that you have created a wallet and have it open

Anyone know what is my error ?

Comment: You should paste your command, I guess!

Answer (score 2):

Create wallet first:

`cleos wallet create`

If wallet locked, unlock it with

`cleos wallet unlock`

or

`cleos wallet unlock --password <YOUR_PASSWORD>`

Comment: Yes, I have create a wallet and unlock it too.
I followed the step in https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/learn-about-wallets-keys-and-accounts-with-cleos
So now I have default and periwinkle wallet,
But when I try to create wallet, it returned that error.
What can I do ?